# Generate custom key using Sequence in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sequences

I'm trying to find a way to use a `Sequence` object to generate a unique key across a few tables (which store different types of the same thing).

The key, however, is made of 2 parts: a unique number from the sequence and a piece from application. There are 25 different instances of the same application each of which have their own designated key. The instance key of the instance that's inserting the record would be the second piece.

I'd rather do this at the data layer, but any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does it have to be "a key" instead of two columns, one showing the application key and the other a sequence number? You can have a primary key on two columns. You can easily create 25 different sequence objects if you need to allow two applications to both have a `1`, both have a `2`, etc. But I fail to see the point of that.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a possibility. This is a legacy code with all domain objects assuming one PK.